# Tool to split MP4 videos

Tags: gratis, video, windows-7

I'm looking for a tool which can split MP4 video files. I have tried Any Video Converter but find that it is unreliable and forces choices on frame size but does not always allow me to choose the existing frame size.

What I want is something very simple:

1. Runs on Windows 7
2. Takes an MP4 file as input
3. Takes a desired file size as input
4. Outputs multiple videos (video_1.mp4, video_2.mp4, etc.) which have the same frame size, same codec (h264, etc.) with a maximum file size as specified
5. Can be command-line or graphical (but prefer graphical)
6. Is free

This seems so simple but I see a lot people talking about a lot of problems with a lot of programs.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free, open-source and widely used
- Supports most video formats
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), Linux and [Mac](http://ffmpegmac.net/).
- Allows to [cut](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5651654/395857):

  Running ffmpeg two times:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 00:30:00 output1.avi
  ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:45:00 output2.avi
  ```

  Or in one command:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 00:30:00 output1.avi \
     -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:45:00 output2.avi
  ```
- Allows to [specify the output's max size](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): `-fs limit_size (output)`
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Comment: Could you please expand about what are those lines for?

Comment: What a question in a comment... `-i <inputfile>` should be obvious.  `-vcodec copy`and `-acodec copy` tell ffmpeg to use stream copying instead of transcoding.  `-ss <time>` tells ffmpeg at which time to start and `-t`tells it how long a video to create.  Reading the documentation would have explained that in much more detail.

Answer (score 3):

A good freeware application for splitting and cutting video files (including mp4) is [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/). It supports a lot of formats and it is multiplatform. You can modify frame size, framerate, codec as you desire. You can also calculate output file size before you begin encoding it.
If you only cut/split video without changing codecs it is very fast!

Here is a screenshot from Avidemux site:

[image]