# Portable visual editor to extract selected parts of MP4 video without reencoding, with ability to navigate to previous/next frame

Tags: windows, video, video-editing, portable

Is there any piece of software that fulfills these three basic requirements?

1. Has some interface to view and listen an opened file (MP4 support is a must, but support for other formats would look like a nice bonus), and navigate through it by next/prev frame.
2. Allows to extract a selected part of a video without reencoding. I don’t even need a super-accurate, frame-level, extraction, just the same level of accuracy as e.g. FFMPEG has.
3. Has a portable version.

Not too much, right? I’ve read lots of similar questions on the Web, such as [questions/21788](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/simple-lossless-video-editor-for-windows-with-mp4-support), [questions/3382](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/tool-to-split-mp4-videos) and [questions/17996](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17996/a-portable-free-and-simple-video-editor), and I am really shocked and sad that I cannot find anything! The following options are excluded:

- Avidemux (has no “official” portable version; I found an unofficial version, but it looks too unstable and buggy — for example, cannot open some files or takes too much time to open; moreover, it cannot even remember two different paths for input and output files which causes me to waste too much time; but the main and intolerable problem is that sometimes the extracted fragment does not even correspond with my selection, even if I use only keyframes as start/end marks!);
- Machete (relies on OS-level codecs; has no portable version, which is common for commercial closed-source software; I tested this app 2-3 years ago, and all I remember is that it could not change the volume of audio!);
- SolveigMMVideoSplitter (it’s widely accepted that its interface is undoubtedly the best, and I fully agree with that — it’s just ideal for me, and I would love to use this app, but... unfortunately, it can often produce files of subpar quality; moreover, it can unexpectedly show some strange messages complaining about input files. But the main problem is that it often crashes and even freezes my OS!);
- VideoToVideo (its development seems to be discontinued since long time ago; moreover, this app has some very user-unfriendly bugs: “Video Splitter” tool cannot navigate to the previous frame, and Commercial Remover/Splitter tool cannot even play audio!);
- VideoReDo (did not even test this commercial app because it obviously has no portable version);
- VirtualDub (this app relies on OS-level codecs and has no support for MP4, but even if I will use external plugin to open MP4, there is no way to save MP4 losslessly);
- XMediaRecode (I must admit that its functionality is more than enough to satisfy my needs, but... the problem lies in its Filters/Preview tab; using this tab annoys me very much — it cannot navigate to the previous frame, it often loses time info and stops functioning without any reason...).

Answer (score 1):

[MP4Joiner](http://www.mp4joiner.org/en/) offers:

1. MP4Joiner is a free application that allows join multiple MP4 files into one without reencoding and without quality loss.

Virus Check indicates the file is [safe](https://www.virustotal.com/en/url/90a02dfe0e2bf0b382e94962db0e0c4c040fbc71ec66608921c86d27bf5a2ec9/analysis/).

Comment: Pending approval, I have edited your answer to be more acceptable (hyperlinked your answer and added reference to your Virus suggestion). Best of luck.